# How to change the date on chartkick?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, chartkick

So my CHart looks like this

[image]

First thing the dates are from 2000.

I have Fuel price objects with regular, medium, premium and diesel to display in chart. I want to put each and every record, like by hour.

my code in view looks like this

```
      <%= line_chart [
  {name: "Regular", data: @latest_fuel_price.regular},
  {name: "Medium", data: @latest_fuel_price.medium},
  {name: "Premium", data: @latest_fuel_price.premium},
  {name: "Diesel", data: @latest_fuel_price.diesel}
     ] %>%>
```

Not sure what i am doing but little guidance on how to bring data to the chart will be helpful. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

According to chartkick guide it should be somthing like this

```
<%= line_chart DATA library: {  
                               hAxis: { format: '(your pattern)' }, 
                               vAxis: { title: '(your axe name)' }
                             } 
%>
```

where DATA is your data selection with dates.

1. [link to charts attributes](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart)
2. [link to date format
   specification](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/classSimpleDateFormat.html#_details)